# Only hide div if no page scroll?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have a div that scrolls up after x seconds I want to make it so if the page has already been scrolled to not scroll up this is the scroll code

```
$(window).load(function () {
$('body,html').delay(6000) //wait
    $('body,html').animate(
    {        
        'scrollTop': $('#topslide').offset().top
    }, 800); //animate over 300ms
});
```

I used this code previously to check where the scroll was in order to show or hide a logo

this was the code used for that

```
var pastWaypoint = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 920 && !pastWaypoint) {    
        $('#logo').show();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','0px');
        pastWaypoint = true;
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 920 && pastWaypoint)
    {
        $('#logo').hide();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','100px');
        pastWaypoint = false;
    }
});
```

just not sure how I could combine the two to get the desired affect.

any suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's delay doesn't have a way to cancel a queued event (AFAIK). Use setTimeout instead, then wrap the function in an `if`. setTimeout does the same thing as delay, but since it wraps a function you can use a conditional statement to do your scroll checking.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){ // The first argument is the function...
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 920)
            {
                $('body,html').animate({        
                    'scrollTop': $('#topslide').offset().top
                }, 800);
            }
    },6000); // This second argument is the time to wait in milliseconds BEFORE the function is called.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JcX7u/

To check if the page has not been scrolled you would use `if (!$(window).scrollTop())`, and to make it wait you would just use setTimeout.

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ // wait 1000ms (time is defined after the func further down)
        if (!$(window).scrollTop()){ // has the page been scrolled?
            $('body,html').animate({        
                'scrollTop': $('#topslide').offset().top
            }, 800); //animate over 800ms
        }
    },1000);
});
```

*I used 1 second in the example to save waiting 6 seconds to see it works*